# Storage type for few data?

Tags: sqlite, caching, storage

I'm developing an sms application and i want just a message and a phone number inserted by user to be stored in memory in order to be automatically retrieved the next time the user opens the application. Which storage type should I use? I think sqlite database would be unnecessary for such a few data... Xml files are read-only. Should I use cache memory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cache memory? Next time you reboot your PC it will be gone. Databases are the best options. If not then a simple text file would suffice I guess. Simple File I/O will be needed every time a user opens your app. Also note in any case you will need encryption/decryption if you are storing passwords.

For XML files you will need to define Xpaths, Parsing logic etc. Better write it in a plain text file with some delimiter like space or comma or *.